# compass install bootstrap -> NoMethodError on line ["32"] ... sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

After running this command

```
compass install bootstrap
```

I get this message:

```
identical sass/styles.scss
```

...

```
identical javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js
NoMethodError on line ["32"] of /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@favy/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

in /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@favy/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb

```
 31     def resolver
 32       options[:custom][:resolver]
 33     end
```

I tried a workaround -> https://gist.github.com/castus/4044953

```
def resolver
  if ::Rails::env == "production"
    options[:custom][:resolver]
  else
    Resolver.new(CompassRails.context)
  end
end
```

& still no luck :)

I have this stuff in my config/compass.rb

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
```

And my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "paperclip"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'

gem 'gmaps4rails'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "Compass" at all if you are using Rails and Bootstrap-sass. Compass is for sites not using Rails.

Here are steps to install and bootstrap-sass

1. Add it to Gemfile and `bundle install`
2. Rename application.css to application.css.scss
3. Remove all comments in application.css.scss, make it blank
4. Add `@import bootstrap`

You are done! Treat it as normal css file and use @import to do whatever you like. But no more `require` in comment!

Comment: Thank you :)
I just want to confirm. Can I use all this stuff (http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) after installing Bootstrap-sass ?

Comment: @whitesiroi, what you mentioned is Compass's CSS framework. You've already have a CSS framework in hand - Twitter bootstrap. Using two together is unnecessary and will have conflict.